# Android: Google maps v2, zoom is not working

Tags: android, google-maps

Programmatically changing camera zoom is not working for me. Take look at the code:

```
public void moveToMyLocation(GoogleMap map)
{
  Criteria crit = new Criteria();
  String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
  Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

  LatLng latlng=new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
  float czoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;  // eq 2.0
  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,(float) 19.6));
  czoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom; // STILL eq 2.0!!
}
```

I can still zoom map using default controls.

m.

Comment: Maybe you can't move the camera and then animate it to the same location. Try to do it in one command.

Comment: Already tried it, it didn't work. The command moves the camera, but zoom appears to be constant

Comment: Try to set smaller zoom level like 3 or 4. Maybe 19.6 not supported in your area. And also try to move to another location and see if it working.

Comment: Nope, the camera does not move. In the same location I can zoom to maximum value using -/+ map controls.

Comment: Try to use `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19.6f)` instead `newLatLngZoom`

Comment: Nope... I think I tried everything. Maybe there are some constraints when comes to zooming?

Comment: I don't thinks so. You didn't try different values?

Comment: Maybe some other code break the zoom level. Try to open new project and change the zoom level there. If its working copy the code to your real project. Then try to isolate the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
                    LatLng(it.position.latitude, it.position.longitude)))

Handler().postDelayed({
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn())
        }, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to zoom directly without the animation :

```
map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(xxxx,xxxx) , 14.0f) );
```

Comment: And vice versa if I'm not mistaken